# Automatically set axis limits to minimum possible boundary showing all plots of grid arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting multiple plots together in R using `grid.arrange`. All of the graphs are similar, so I want them to have a similar scale for the sake of comparison. Is there a generic command I could use to select the narrowest possible `limits` for `scale_y_continuous` that includes all of the plots (predictions and upper/lower bounds of confidence intervals?

If the plots cannot all have the same scale, is there a generic command such that at least all plots could have their **respective** narrowest boundaries possible.

For example, given the following plots:

```
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

mod1 <- feols(hp ~ vs * am | carb, data = mtcars)

# extract raw data for plotting
dat1 <- plot_slopes(mod1, variables = "vs", condition = "am", draw = FALSE)

# convert categorical (binary/factor) variable to numeric
dat1$am <- as.numeric(as.character(dat1$am))

plot1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = am, y = estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = .2) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(y = "Slopes")


mod2 <- feols(hp ~ vs * am + mpg | carb, data = mtcars)

# extract raw data for plotting
dat2 <- plot_slopes(mod2, variables = "vs", condition = "am", draw = FALSE)

# convert categorical (binary/factor) variable to numeric
dat2$am <- as.numeric(as.character(dat2$am))

plot2 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x = am, y = estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = .2) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(y = "Slopes")

 grid.arrange(plot1,plot2)
```

How can I select the narrowest possible `scale_y_continous` that would fit both plots predictions and the lows and highs of their shaded confidence intervals? If the same scale cannot be used for both plots, can their respective narrowest scales be used? I would like to do this for many plots, so automating the process would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the existing ranges from the plots using `layer_scales`, so we can do

```r
newlims <- range(c(layer_scales(plot1)$y$range$range, 
                   layer_scales(plot2)$y$range$range))

grid.arrange(plot1 + ylim(newlims), plot2 + ylim(newlims))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, this is such a smart solution! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make the plots all have the same scale using `scale_y_continous(limits = c(lower, upper), breaks =c(lower, middle, middle_2, _upper)).`

You can set identical lower and upper limits and keep the graphs comparable on the same scale.

My intuition, though, is that what you're asking is "*is there a command within `scale_y_continuous` that will automatically pick the lowest and highest possible bounds?*"

My understanding is that the answer to that question is no, but you may be able to manually identify the graph with the lowest/highest bounds and input that value for all subsequent graphs.